# Fluent NHibernate: SQLite in-memory database and GUID generated on insert

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using SQLite in-memory database for testing purposes. One of the entities has a column map
that generate GUID on insert operation.

```
this.Map(v => v.Code).Generated.Insert().ReadOnly();
```

First of all GUID doesn't get generated and every record inserted has an empty GUID.
Secondly, I cannot retrieve an entity by empty GUID.

```
this.Session.Query<Entity>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code == code);
```

Everything is fine when I generate GUID on the client side manually prior to saving entity.

Anyone has a similar issue?

Thanks

Comment: Not really an expert in NH, but in the project I'm working on, an auto-GUID is mapped like this: `Map(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned().Not.Nullable()`

Comment: This is not an Id column that I'm using for the GUID code. Basically, my code is working fine without any problem with real MSSQL database. This issue related only to SQLite in-memory database that I'm using for testing.

Answer (score 0):

How Connection string look like? Maybe "data source=:memory:;BinaryGuid=False" fixes this.

Comment: I'm using fluent configuration SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory()

Comment: Then `SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.Raw("connection.release_mode", "on_close").ConnectionString("data source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;BinaryGuid=False");`

Comment: BinaryGuid=False didn't help. still entity Guid doesn't get generated.

Comment: Seems `ReadOnly()` blocks generation.

Comment: removed `ReadOnly()` still no Guids